# How to embed on a power-point presentation an interactive window created with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerpoint

I have created a window using PySimpleGUI using the code bellow. I would like to use this window on a full screen power-point presentation.

How could I get that interactive window embedded on the presentation?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# Demo of how columns work
# window has on row 1 a vertical slider followed by a COLUMN with 7 rows
# Prior to the Column element, this layout was not possible
# Columns layouts look identical to window layouts, they are a list of lists of elements.

window = sg.Window('Columns')                                   # blank window

# Column layout
col = [[sg.Text('col Row 1')],
       [sg.Text('col Row 2'), sg.Input('col input 1')],
       [sg.Text('col Row 3'), sg.Input('col input 2')],
       [sg.Text('col Row 4'), sg.Input('col input 3')],
       [sg.Text('col Row 5'), sg.Input('col input 4')],
       [sg.Text('col Row 6'), sg.Input('col input 5')],
       [sg.Text('col Row 7'), sg.Input('col input 6')]]

layout = [[sg.Slider(range=(1,100), default_value=10, orientation='v', size=(8,20)), sg.Column(col)],
          [sg.In('Last input')],
          [sg.OK()]]

# Display the window and get values

window = sg.Window('Compact 1-line window with column', layout)
event, values = window.Read()
window.Close()

sg.Popup(event, values, line_width=200)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Do you want to open a PowerPoint presentation inside/with this UI, or have this UI inside a presentation?

Comment: Have this UI inside.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that's possible?

Comment: [As Microsoft documents](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-content-from-other-applications-into-powerpoint-8165a079-e639-4278-81be-8b3ee94f81fb), only external applications supporting OLE can be embedded in PowerPoint. I have no reason to believe that support was ever written for PySimpleGUI.

Comment: Can you "embed" an any EXE file inside of power point?  Perhaps turn it into an EXE first using Pyinstaller?

Comment: If you do get this to work, I'm HIGHLY interested! So please report back.  Working on some power points that use PySimpleGUI examples and it would be awesome if they "ran"